# Isole Ip address from dhcp-range

Tags: regex, bash, variables, sed

I would like to extract the Bcast Ip Address from dhcp-range line which is specified in the server configuration file.

dhcp-range=192.168.42.1,192.168.42.253,255.255.255.0,192.168.42.255,24h

I would like to store in a variable 192.168.42.255

Actually I am using

```
DNSMASQ_DIR="dnsmasq.conf"
if [ -e "$DNSMASQ_DIR" ]; then
    BcastAddress=`sed -n 3p $DNSMASQ_DIR | awk '{print $1}'`
    b=${BcastAddress:53:66}
    echo $BcastAddress
    echo $b
else
    echo "file not exists"
fi
```

which returns :

```
dhcp-range=192.168.42.1,192.168.42.253,255.255.255.0,192.168.42.255,24h
192.168.42.255,24h
```

I don't understand why ,24h is included. At the same time, I think that my method will be not efficient if the other IP addresses change. Is there a more efficient way to resolve my issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it in `awk`

```
$ echo "dhcp-range=192.168.42.1,192.168.42.253,255.255.255.0,192.168.42.255,24h" | awk -F, '{print $4}'
192.168.42.255
```

**Simplified version of your code**

You can even simplify the entire script using awk as

```
$ awk -F, '/^dhcp-range/{print $4}' dnsmasq.conf
192.168.42.255
```

- `-F,` sets the field seperator as `,`
- `/^dhcp-range/` selects line starting with `dhcp-range`
- `print $4` prints the fourth column`

**OR**

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==3{print $4}' dnsmasq.conf
192.168.42.255
```

- `NR==3` selects the third line

Comment: Thank once again nu11p01n73R !

Answer (score 2):

You can refer cut command also

```
cut -d',' -f4 dnsmasq.conf
```

**Example :**

```
DNSMASQ_DIR="dnsmasq.conf"
if [ -e "$DNSMASQ_DIR" ]; then
    b=`sed -n 3p $DNSMASQ_DIR | cut -d',' -f4 `
    echo $b
else
    echo "file not exists"
fi
```

Sed command printed 3rd line and cut command extract the 4th column delimiter of `,`

**Output :**

```
192.168.42.255
```

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker,Updated my answer.